# PDO throws connection error about "trust" authentication when using pgbouncer for one database, but not another. Settings are identical

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, postgresql-11, pgbouncer

This problem is driving me batty. I have a PHP script which connects to a postgresql database, and I have pgbouncer running for connection pooling.

I've tested it using two databases, and it works just fine for both when I connect directly. Here is my connection code:

```
        $dbuser='db1'; $dbpass='db1'; $dbname='db1';

        $dsn="pgsql:port=5432;host=/var/run/postgresql;dbname=$dbname";

        $options = [
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
                PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
        ];
        try {
                $pg_pdo=new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass, $options); 
        } catch (\PDOException $e) {
                throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
        }
```

This code, with `db1`, works just fine whether I keep the port 5432, or change the port to to 6432. When I change the databasename, user, and password to `db2`, it also works fine on port 5432.

But when I am connecting to the second database *and* set the port to 6432, I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] ERROR:  "trust" authentication failed
```

Now, I've already checked my `/etc/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.ini`, it contains the lines:

```
[databases]
* =
```

Meaning that the connection info for any databases is simply being forwarded. Neither db1 nor db2 is mentioned in the file.

Also, my `/var/lib/pgsql/11/data/pg_hba.conf` file:

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all              postgres                                peer
local   db1              db1                                     md5
local   db2              db2                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 ident
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 ident
```

Yes, I've restarted both pgbouncer.service and postgresql-11.service.

I can't for the life of me figure out why PHP's PDO is falling back on the "trust" authentication method, I don't want it to do this, I want it to send the password normally.

And why would it be working with one database and not the other? Is this a question of the `db2` role lacking some sort of privilege that `db1` is granted, or something about the database being different?

In case it is relevant, my environment is PHP 7.4, PostgreSQL 11.12, and pgbouncer 1.15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved this myself. Apparently it is also necessary to edit the `/etc/pgbouncer/userlist.txt` file:

This file had a listing for db1, but not db2. Adding the second line (format is "username" "password"):

```
"db2" "db2"
```

However, this was insufficient to fix the problem. Apparently, I had created this file as root. It needs to be owned by pgbouncer, so this command was necessary:

```
chown pgbouncer:pgbouncer /etc/pgbouncer/userlist.txt
```

These two changes fixed the problem. Thank you to [this link](https://arthurpemberton.com/2016/01/pgbouncer-giving-you-no-such-user-errors) for helping me, and for [this thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/245784/pgbouncer-getting-auth-failing-when-trying-to-connect-using-psql) for a more thorough explanation of how the pgbouncer configuration works.